# Is there a name for the matrix operation $ABA^t$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices

I know in group theory, the operation $ABA^{-1}$, i.e. the element A multiplied by the element B, and then multiplied by the inverse of A, is called conjugation.

When dealing with matrices, there is a similar operation that happens frequently: $ABA^{t}$, where instead of multiplying by the inverse of A, you multiply by the transpose of A. Does this operation or the resulting matrix have a name?

Comment: The answer below is probably the best. It's also a sort of pullback of the bilinear form $B$ represents.

Comment: The conjugation with inverse can be called matrix similarity https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_similarity

Answer (score 4):

The name that seems to be the closest is the [congruence transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congruent_transformation).

Answer (score 2):

If $A$ is orthogonal, it is a *change of basis*.