# Meaning of matrix $ABA^T$

Tags: linear-algebra

I see this kind of multiplication all over the place and was wondering if there was some intuitive meaning behind it. I tried searching for this general form, but nothing came up.

The most recent example of this that I have seen is for the Kalman filter prediction and measurement update:

$P'=FPF^T$

$S=HPH^T$

Comment: Are you are asking what the notation $ABA^T$ means?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I see it in so many places, but have only just done those operations, but because of how often and in different places I see that I started to think it must have a meaning

Comment: Do you know conjugation? $ABA^{-1}$. And orthogonal "conjugation" is $ABA^T$. See for example [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3630761/is-there-a-name-for-the-matrix-operation-abat).

Comment: A special case of it is the [Gram matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram_matrix).

Comment: @DietrichBurde I think congruence transformation are a bit too restrictive, because they require, by definition, that $A$ invertible. However, this kind of term appears quite often when $A$ is rectangular as well.

Comment: Closel related is the matrix of a [Bilinear form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_form).